# ng ui-grid filter on startup

Tags: angular, ui-grid

I can filter on a button click fine with:

```
$scope.filter = function (value) {
        // todo: might need to get data via ajax here to reduce loading at the start
        console.log("Filter value '" + value + "' selected.");
        $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[7].filters[0] = { term: value };
    }
```

But, I'm trying to predefine 1 filter for 1 column on startup with the below but it does nothing.

```
$scope.grid = {
...
filterOptions: { filterText: 'Open', filterColumn: 'Status', useExternalFilter: false },
...
};
```

How do I pre-define a filter on a column?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when I'm defining my column I can do:

```
filter: { term: 'value_here' }
```

Comment: but can we do it on conditions like when the page preloads with a action that one filter should be filtered as per the data we got.